# How to write a C#/ASP.NET MVC 3(razor) based, simple, photo gallery?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, photo-gallery

I can do this in Javascript by pulling a series of thumbnails as an array. Then I know when I'm on the first photo, or the last, and can show controls based on that.

How can this efficiently be done on the server side using C#/ASP.NET MVC 3(razor)? [For example, on my site here, is one photo, out of 19 photos.](http://www.atmybase.com/yokota-ab-japan/Places/ShowPhoto/359) I'd like to add next/prev functionality.

Do I have to pull the entire array of photos, parse out the current photo, determine if it's first or last, then build next/prev buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a photo gallery, there is **One photo from many photos**, and when there is a concept like **x items from y items** in which `x < y`, then we all think of **paging**. Photo gallery is almost like a grid with one item and two buttons for going to the next page and previous page. If you want to implement paging by yourself, there is no need to **fetch all photos and compare them to the current photo** to create next/previous buttons. All you have to do, is to cache current item index and the count of all photos, and on each rendering, calculate to see if you need to render next, previous, or next and previous buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Making **one complete page load per image is inefficient, slow** and will send your visitors away of your site quickly.

I have recently creating a [decently fast ASP.NET MVC photo gallery](http://www.aspphotogallery.net/mvcphotogallery/) using the following techniques:

1. When the visitor clicks on a certain folder an ajax request is sent to the server requesting the folder's thumbnail collection (the data is returned in JSON format)
2. The thumbnails and other UI components are rendered using a model view view-model framework called [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) (btw, it is great!). The information retrieved from the server is passed directly to the knockout binding model in JSON format, so you don't have to do any serialization or marshalling.
3. When the user clicks on a certain thumbnail, an ajax call is issued to the server, to retrieve a JSON object containing the image information: a) the main image URL c) next and prev images (if any) d) exif information c) comments for that image, etc.
4. Knockout.js knows how to render the prev and next arrows (if any), and all the other information to the UI view-model, so they refresh automatically.

If you combine that with some server side caching, you'll have a pretty fast photo gallery application.

Cheers!!

iván

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a client technology, Silverlight, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Webforms, WPF, Winforms..
The concept is as follows.

1. Choose a client /presentation technology
2. Decide where the photos are going to come from (Database, Webservice (Infront of a database)
3. Create methods to get next and previous photos for a specific series (Album, User, Globally)
4. Call these methods on a Forward or Backward (button/image) click.

Comment: Good call, I sure didn't specify. I added in ASP.NET MVC 3/razor.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this going in several ways:

1. Create an aspx page which gets the first photo and create buttons that call this same aspx page, but with a query string of the next or prev photo, as needed. This solution will cause postbacks, so you need to decide if this works for you or not.
2. Create an aspx page which gets you a photo based on the query string and call it via jQuery ajax.
3. Create an ASHX file which returns a different image for a query string parameter and make it the SRC for the image.

These three methods allow you different levels of interactivity vs. postback. If you decide which route you would like to take, we can help you get there :)

Comment: I was really thinking about the 2nd option. Perhaps making a json call to an action, and one of the parts of info coming back would say whether it's the last/first photo. hmm....

Comment: Make a jquery ajax request to an action (really simple to do) and return two things, a URL for the photo and a status. The status would be 0 for both back and forth enabled, 1 for only back (last photo) and 2 for only forth (first photo). Just one idea, off the top of mmy head.

Comment: This is a good ref for jquery ajax and MVC: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/09/08/using-jquery-ajax-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-get-and-getjson-vs-post.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you go for this in C#. While doing it in C# i will use **ajax call**. For this i will load only the first image and Total image count initially.

According to the total count and current image no show the prev and next button.

On clicking the next and prev button take the corresponding image from db using ajax call.

I dont know how to use but there are many jquery plugins to show gallery